# how to read input from barcode scanner and only display required content?

Tags: vb.net

Example: barcode content is 1|123456|78910 but i want to retrieve only 123456
Here is my code: Currently my code retrieve all the barcode content.

```
Private Sub TextVendorID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
TextVendorID.TextChanged
        Dim s As String = TextVendorID.Text
        s = Mid(s, 3, 5)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Everytime your textbox's content changes, the TextChanged event will be fired. What if there is only 1 character in your textbox? Your Mid(..) will result in an exception. Try using the Validating event. And use the substring method of the string class. Also, strings use 0-based index by default.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I try to use this code. it work but the length of the vendor id for every barcode are different. Anyone can help me please

Private Sub TextVendorID_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextVendorID.KeyPress
        TextVendorID.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper

        Dim a As String
        Dim s As String

        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 13 Then
            a = Mid(TextVendorID.Text, 2, 5)
            TextVendorID.Text = a
        End If
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This code will do the job, assuming that all barcodes have three parts separated by a "|" character.

The length of the vendor ID (I assume it is the middle string between the "|" character) is not relevant.

Your input string will be split into an array based on the "|" character. strSplit(0) will = 1, strSplit(1) will = 123456 and strSplit(2) will = 78910. The pipes ("|") will be dropped.

```
Private Sub TextVendorID_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextVendorID.TextChanged
    Try
        Dim strSplit() As String = TextVendorID.Text.Split("|")
        If strSplit.Count > 2 Then
            TextVendorID.Text = strSplit(1)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```